# Is there a minhag or halacha to avoid kashering vessels for Passover and to only use new vessels

Tags: halacha, minhag, passover, kashering-kosherization

I was told by my father that we follow the minhag not to kasher vessels for paisach but to buy new ones

I asked a Rav, the Rav said there is no such minhag, no reason to avoid kashering even when easy

But now I found [this video](http://chabad.info/video/beis-medrash-video/%d7%a9%d7%99%d7%a2%d7%95%d7%a8%d7%99-%d7%94%d7%a8%d7%91-%d7%a0%d7%97%d7%9e%d7%a0%d7%a1%d7%95%d7%9f/%d7%94%d7%9c%d7%9b%d7%95%d7%aa-%d7%98%d7%91%d7%99%d7%9c%d7%aa-%d7%9b%d7%9c%d7%99%d7%9d-%d7%9c%d7%a4%d7%a1%d7%97)

who is correct?

Sources on subject greatly appreciated

Comment: many prefer not to kasher thing for pesach as chametz is never batel. There is always a small chance that not 100% is removed. Unlike other areas of kashrus which mainly deals with the taste of the item when it comes to chametz it doesn't matter if the taste isn't present b/c the prohibition is on the chametz itself.

Comment: Is it possible to have a source that there is no such _minhag_?

Comment: @WAF the vedio is wrong?

Comment: I don't have access to the video. If possible, can you summarize its contents? Certain materials can't be koshered no matter what. I think stoneware and Correl may be 2 examples. In my home, we kasher glass as well as silver flatware and Kiddush cups. They are sterling, not silver plate. Have been doing this for years, so I'm unaware that there is a steadfast minhag to buy new silverware. I certainly don't have the money to do that!

Comment: @dude chametz is batel. It just cannot be batel on pesach itself, but before pesach chametz can be batel.

Comment: @DanF poiskim say you should try not to do hagolo but to buy new vassals

Comment: The Chasam sofer did not keep this minhag. See Shu”t Y.D.110. He uses the fact that we can kasher things for pesach as a way around the minhag not to kasher from dairy to meat. I might add that following this chasam sofer halacha limsa is a very common practice these days.

Comment: @hazoriz You mean "vessels". Yes, I read Magen AVraham. Quite interesting. However, if I understood what he stated correctly, it seems that hagalh is possible when buying new items is impractical. My deduction from this is that buying a new very expensive set of silverware is impractical. Yes, you can use plasticware just for the point of buying new. But, there's also a halacha to beautify your Seder table. And, IMO, when you have 20 people staying with you for all of Pesach, all that new disposable plasticware becomes pricey as well. I think there may be room to be lenient, here.

Comment: @TzafnasPaneach +1 interesting, but from the answer below it seems that even the people that do keep it, hold that you can kasher for paisach

Comment: @DanF I was sending you what was in the video, pesochim 30b Rabina asked R. Ashi: What does one do about the knives on Passover?  — I provide [make] new ones for myself, he replied. That is well for you, who can [afford] this, said he to him,  [but] what about one who cannot [afford] this?  I mean like new  ones, he answered: [I thrust] their handles in loam, and their blades in fire, and then I place their handles in boiling water.     But the law is: both the one and the other [need only be put] into boiling water, and in a ‘first’ vessel

Comment: @hazoriz So, it appears that there is some leniency for those that cannot afford it, right?

Comment: @DanF It seems to me  that to buy new is mitzva min hamuvchar, and only when possible. so if cannot afford it, it is not a leniency, (it is the halocho) that he can kasher. But I have another question if it is only regarding knifes or also other vessels

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll find it in the [Magen Avraham 451, 6.](http://beta.hebrewbooks.org/tursa.aspx?a=oc_x2199)

Comment: +1 thank you ([shulchan aruch harav 451.14](http://chabadlibrary.org/books/adhaz/sh/sh3/1/451/14.htm) is easier for me to understand)